# Remove html junk like style=""

Tags: css, styles, inline

My website  is build on Wordpress using the Theme "BeTheme", which creates html junk like empty inline styles (style="").

How can I remove this?

I thought of two ways: If I would know in which php-File the style attribute is attached, I could do something like

```
if (style is empty)
{
   don't attach style attribute
}
```

If I can't get there, I could clean the page afterwards with something like

```
replace(style="", '')
```

How can I achive this in an elegant way, without slowing my page down?

Comment: What is your reasoning for wanting to do this? Sure you can remove all the empty style attributes but running this over every single element in your DOM seems like extra execution steps that don't need to be run. My point here is that the empty style tags don't hurt anything, so why go through the effort to remove them? If you still want to do this, you could always duplicate the theme and fix it so it doesn't add the styles.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($("div").attr("style").length<=0)
{
  $("div").removeAttr("style");
}
```

Comment: THX so far!

I want to do this for SEO reasons. Several tools tell me that the site has "spaghetti code" because of the inline css.

I want my site to be fast and dont waste time with useless css.

Thanks for the code, but I have no idea where to put is so it will work properly.